# Why I cannot connect to Kafka from outside?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, virtual-machine

I am running kafka on ec2 instance. So amazon ec2 instance has two ips one is internal ip and second one is for external use.

I created producer from local machine, but it redirect to internal ip and give me connection unsuccessful error. Can anybody help me to configure kafka on ec2 instance, so that I can run producer from local machine. I am tried many combinations but didn't work.

Answer (score 49):

In the [Kafka FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whycan%27tmyconsumers/producersconnecttothebrokers?) (updated for new properties) you can read:

> When a broker starts up, it registers its ip/port in ZK. You need to make sure the registered ip is consistent with what's listed in `bootstrap.servers` in the producer config. By default, the registered ip is given by `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress()`. Typically, this should return the real ip of the host. However, sometimes (e.g., in EC2), the returned ip is an internal one and can't be connected to from outside. The solution is to explicitly set the host ip and port to be registered in ZK by setting the `advertised.listeners` property in `server.properties`.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the mentioned hostname property in server.properties is called: `host.name=<external-ip>`

Comment: I am in the rare case: `In another rare case where the binding host/port is different from the host/port for client connection, you can set advertised.host.name and advertised.port for client connection.`. How do I do this?

Comment: It's "host.name" not "hostname".

Comment: `host.name` is [deprecated](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) - as are `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port`

Comment: wanted to add a link to my blog post to compliment this answer https://boristyukin.com/connecting-to-kafka-on-virtualbox-from-windows/

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D You are wrong. Because it worked out for me.

Comment: @c0de Deprecated means it won't work forever, but it currently works

Answer (score 41):

I solved this problem, by setting `advertised.host.name` in `server.properties` and `metadata.broker.list` in `producer.properties` to public IP address and `host.name` to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @ sms_1190 ..Hi.. I am facing the same issues. I have kafka set up running in ec2 linux. I have written java code in eclipse installed in windows machine.I am able to create events in eclipse but i don't see them in kafka producer which is running in ec2. How to connect your eclipse or kafka code in maven in windows to connect to ec2 linux. I have modified advertised.host.name and advertised.port in kafka server config and also metadata.broker.list in producer as pub ip:0000.

Comment: @user3858193: Check your security groups in ec2. you should open 9092 port to 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: 1) can you please paste (those two lines) here the actual changes which you made in server.properties and producer.properties. 2) which kafka version are you using? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @sms_1190 and did you have any properties file on your windows machine or every config file is only at the EC2? Thanks again.

Comment: This absolutely solved one week of breaking the head. High five! Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way how to reach your Kafka server (version kafka_2.11-1.0.0) on EC2 from consumer in external network is to change the properties file

```
kafka_2.11-1.0.0/config/server.properties
```

And modify the following line

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
```

Using your public address

Verified on 2.11-2.0.0

Comment: worked as a charm :-) ... thanks P. Koncz. You can also, via command line, override it `--override listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9092`

Comment: Hi, I have installed confluent-oss-5.0.0 on Azure VM and I am trying to access through Public IP to consume messages. Port is opened. NO LUCK, it's not working after changing all you have suggested. Getting below error :~/confluent-kafka/confluent-oss-5.0.0/bin$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list 13.71.115.20:9092 --topic pj_test123
>sdf
[2019-03-25 18:23:11,288] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {pj_test123=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Answer (score 16):

I just did this in AWS.  First get the Kafka server to listen on the correct interface/IP using host.name.  For your case this would be the internal IP, not localhost, since your intent is for outside Kafka clients to connect.  Any local clients will need to use that same address, not localhost.

Then set advertised.host.name to a host name, not an IP address.  The trick is to get that host name to always resolve to the correct IP for both internal and external machines.  I use /etc/hosts inside and DNS outside.  See my [full answer about Kafka and name resolution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880811/kafka-quickstart-advertised-host-name-gives-kafka-common-leadernotavailableexce/32400265#answer-32400265).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access from LAN, change following 2 files-

1. In `config/server.properties`:

   ```
   advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://server.ip.in.lan:9092
   ```
2. In `config/producer.properties`:

   ```
   bootstrap.servers=server.ip.in.lan:9092
   ```

In my case, the `server.ip.in.lan` value was `192.168.15.150`

Answer (score 3):

Below are the steps to connect Kafka from outside of EC2 instance.

1. Open Kafka server properties file on EC2.

   /kafka_2.11-2.0.0/config/server.properties
2. Set the value of advertised.listeners to

   > advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092

   This should be your Public DNS (IPv4) of EC2 instance.
3. Stop Kafka server.
4. Start Kafka server to see above configuration changes in action.
5. Now you can connect to your Kafka of EC2 instance from outside or from your localhost.

   Tried and tested on kafka_2.11-2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

SSH to your EC2 instance or wheverver you're hosting Kafka.

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Add:

`127.0.0.1 <your-host-name> localhost`

In my case it's:

`127.0.0.1 ec2-12-34-56-78.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Save and exit.

Comment: Editing hosts file is a hack and should be avoided. `advertised.listeners` is the real solution to the problem, and is not specific to Unix environments

Answer (score -1):

For EC2 you should edit the `/etc/hosts` file to add:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ip-YYY-YYY-YYY-YYY
```

where XXX... is your external IP and the ip-YYY-YYY-YYY-YYY is the string returned by the `hostname` command. You can use `127.0.0.1` instead of your external IP to communicate inside the server.

`host.name` is [deprecated](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) - as are `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port`

Comment: See also: https://github.com/ModernMT/MMT/issues/276#issuecomment-334099367

Comment: This is a hack, and not correct. `advertised.listeners` is correct. The clients should get the addresses from Zookeeper, not the local machine's host file.