# Open a port for Kafka communication to the outside-world

Tags: linux, azure, configuration, port, apache-kafka

I have a VM (Linux OS) in Azure which has Hortonworks on it, which launches Kafka.

- Kafka service is running and I am able of creating producer and consumer inside the VM.
- I have the server IP and I'm also able to log into Ambari using 8080 port.
- When I am trying to send a message to Kafka from my Java application I get a TimoutEception after 60 seconds.

What do I need to do in order to set the right port for Kafka communication from outside the VM?

I think that the m,ain issue here, is that Kafka is listening on local IP and not on the VM IP (WAN).

Any help will be really appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set Kafka advertised.host.name and advertised.port environment variables? That's how you present yourself to the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used the Azure Resource Manager workflow to create the VM you have a Network Security Group that has been created automatically. You need to create rules in the NSG to make Kafka available. See : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

If you have used the Azure classic deployment workflow, you need to define an endpoint to expose Kafka. See: https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/

Hope this helps,

Julien

Comment: Done that. The main problem is that Kafka service run under internal IP. How can I forward external VM request to Kafka? :)

Comment: have you an azure load balancer in front of your machine ? if yes, you need to define a NAT rule in the LB. If no, there is nothing else to do at the Azure network level. Do you have any firewall on your VM ?

Comment: + can you post a screen of the inbound rules you have defined, please ?

Comment: I do not have a loadbalancer - this is a sort of POC project, I think the problem is with kafka configurations and not Azure. Would the screenshot help?

Answer (score 0):

([Copy and pasting my response to a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844327/918858))

For the recent versions of Kafka (0.10.0 as of this writing), you don't want to use `advertised.host.name` at all. In fact, even the [documentation] states that `advertised.host.name` is already deprecated.  Moreover, Kafka will use this not only as the "advertised" host name for the producers/consumers, but for *other brokers* as well (in a multi-broker environment)...which is kind of a pain if you're using using a different (perhaps internal) DNS for the brokers...and you really don't want to get into the business of adding entries to the individual `/etc/hosts` of the brokers (ew!)

So, basically, you would want the brokers to use the internal name, but use the external FQDNs for the producers and consumers *only*.  To do this, you will update `advertised.listeners` instead.