# Missing a step into opening kafka to outside world

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a setup a local kafka node that I want to open to the open world.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395769/open-a-port-for-kafka-communication-to-the-outside-world) which seems very similar. I have opened that port using the advertised listeners to `localhost:9092` and I opened that port the node, but when I'm trying to produce a message using `kafkajs` I get the following error :

`{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2021-06-01T13:49:35.225Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 13.36.134.166:9092","broker":"13.36.134.166:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 13.36.134.166:9092\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)"}`

Am I missing a big step here ? Is using `localhost` to designate the advertised port ?

Many thanks ! Kev.

Comment: Have you added `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` in server.properties?

Comment: The error says either `13.36.134.166` is blocked, or `:9092` at that address is not allowed through the firewall, or the server itself has not opened that port. You can use `nc -vz 13.36.134.166 9092` as a very basic network check rather than write Kafka code. Advertising localhost is definitely not correct

Comment: Ho.. well I've added `localhost:9092` instead of an other adress in the `server.properties`file... I'll have to try with `0.0.0.0`