# Kafka cannot startup on ubuntu instance, getLocalHost(InetAddress) returns ip with "ip" appended to the beginning of the ip

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

Running ubuntu on AWS. When I try to start up Kafka I see this exception:

```
[2018-07-22 06:18:44,467] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-153-166-139: ip-10-153-166-139: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaServer.scala:390)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaServer.scala:388)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createBrokerInfo(KafkaServer.scala:388)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:256)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-153-166-139: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 13 more
[2018-07-22 06:18:44,469] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

I've noticed this since I started using this image:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-153-166-139:
```

Why does "ip" get appended to the instance ip the kafka server is trying to use to fully start up? Is there a system config I can change so just the ip itself gets returned by getLocalHost?

Comment: The ip-10-153-166-139 is the internal DNS hostname that resolves to the primary private IPv4 address of your EC2 instance. See if the answer to this SO helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191347/why-i-cannot-connect-to-kafka-from-outside?rq=1

Comment: Show your Kafka Server properties file

Comment: @mazaneicha exactly what I needed, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended above, answer was here:

[Why I cannot connect to Kafka from outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191347/why-i-cannot-connect-to-kafka-from-outside?rq=1)

Inside /kafka/config/server.properties add:

host.name='actual.ip.of.the.box'