# Not able to produce kafka-messages from outside AWS Kafka cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am having the following issue:

I set up an as basic as possible confluent platform on aws using only 1 worker and broker node.

When i try to produce messages towards my kafka topic from outside my vpc, i am getting the following error message:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic test1 with key: null, value:
>   13 bytes with error:
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update
>   metadata after 60000 ms.

when i do this from within the vpc network, it simply works.

I made sure my vpc allows all traffic and i am aware of using the public dns addresses of my ec2 nodes.

i also had a look at this one [Why I cannot connect to Kafka from outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191347/why-i-cannot-connect-to-kafka-from-outside/27194113)

I implemented the changes, but i did not solve my issue.

I am very nocive with everything that has to do with connections and networks, so I hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 1):

Problem got solved: configuring advertised listeners did the trick + working outside the company firewall. –