# kafka-python timeout when producer send msg to topic in docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-python

1. I have three kafka hosts which run in real hosts;
2. I want to send msg to kafka in a docker container, This container can connect to kafka hosts;
3. When I send msg in docker container use kafka-python,It always taken timout error,like this:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/producer/future.py", line 65, in get
    raise self.exception # pylint: disable-msg=raising-bad-type
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Batch for TopicPartition(topic='online_model_msg', partition=0) containing 1 record(s) expired: 46 seconds have passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Dose sb know how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you share your code?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I had resolved,thx.

Comment: Modify the kafka config property in server.properties and producer.properties as this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879712/6487436.